# Javascript class constructed object is undefined

Tags: javascript, class

New with JavaScript. Can someone help me understand why calling `print()` returns undefined?

```
class Quizer {
    constructor(quizObj) {
        this.quiz = quizObj;
    }
    print() {
        console.log(quiz.title);
    }
};
var quizObjects = {
    title: "Quiz1"
};
```

Constructing:

```
var quiz = new Quizer(quizObjects);
quiz.print(); //undefined
```

Comment: where is printAllQuestions()?

Comment: Ah mistake on my end. I meant print(), not printAllQuestions()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problems with your code are,

```
class Quizer {
    constructor(quizObj) {
      this.quiz = quizObj;
    }
    print() {
      console.log(quiz.title);
      //You are not using the `this` context here to access the quiz
      //you have a variable quiz outside the class declaration that points the instance of this class.
     //That will get hoisted and will be accessed here.

    }
};

var quizObjects = { title: "Quiz1" };
var quiz = new Quizer(quizObjects);
quiz.printAllQuestions(); //undefined
//--------^^^^ printAllQuestions is not a member function of Quizer
```

Solution:

```
class Quizer {
    constructor(quizObj) {
      this.quiz = quizObj;
    }
    print() {
      console.log(this.quiz.title);
    }
};

var quizObjects = { title: "Quiz1" };
var quiz = new Quizer(quizObjects);
quiz.print(); //Quiz1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're not much familiar with class syntax yet, the below should work as well.

```
Quizer = function (quizObj) {
    this.quiz = quizObj;
};
Quizer.prototype = {
    print: function () {
        console.log(this.quiz.title);
    }
}
var quizObjects = { title: "Quiz1" };
var quiz = new Quizer(quizObjects);
quiz.print();
```